# Why am I getting a NullPointerException with different classes for Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, step-definitions

Currently I am unable to run classes present in different step definition files in cucumber under same package.How do I make it run?
I am getting a `NullPointerException` in the console for the methods in the different page.

Comment: Made title something that describes actual question.  If you want good answers, titles like 'about cucumber' will not attract them.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. Are you saying that some of your step definitions work and some don't? Can you explain your project structure a bit more?

Comment: Based on the very limited info provided it sounds like the instance is not instantiated between the two.  At run time you need to have an active class instance running for each and share it if it's supposed to be the same instance.  Please provide a lot more info if you want any sort of specific answer.